# Perl: How to Avoid Globals and Keep Database Connection

Tags: database, perl, sqlite

SO.

Perhaps the title is too general for the specific problem I'm having.

I have a Perl script which connects to a SQLite database. During runtime I perform a lot of database operations such as SELECTs, INSERTs, UPDATEs, etc. I wrapped each database operation in its own subroutine (mainly to hide the SQL statement and any additional processing of the result set).

I want to use the same database handler object every time I need to invoke one of this database operation subroutine, so what I have been doing is to pass the database handler object as an argument. For instance:

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect( "dbi:SQLite:dbname=db.db", "", "") or die;

sub select_from_systems {
    my $dbh = shift;
    return $dbh->selectcol_arrayref("SELECT hostname FROM systems");
}
```

Just as a side note, I'm using Perl DBI.

I'm just wondering if there's a more clever way to do this so I don't have to pass the database handler object as an argument.

I would like to avoid global variables, I don't feel they are the plague and in this case it may be justified, but still.

Any help or insight is greatly appreciated.

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you truly want your database handler to be a Singleton (e.g. one per Perl process), you can:

- Use an `our` scoped alias to a global variable. This isn't as tidy as OO approach, but it typically works perfectly well with no downsides - one of the few rare cases where `our` is recommended.
- Set it up as `our` but create class level (e.g. non-object) setter and getter methods for it.
- Set it up as a real singleton. The technique is discussed here: [How can I implement a singleton class in perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310341/how-can-i-implement-a-singleton-class-in-perl)

Comment: Thanks for a handful of options. Given the state of my code and the deadline I'll go with your second solution, the our scoped alias. It just fits becasue what I found quite cumbersome was to pass that argument every single time, I already know what it was I just needed it in the subroutine's scope. Thanks a lot for your time!

Answer (score 4):

Make your module object-oriented. This will still pass the handle as an argument, but with nicer syntax.

```
package MyConnection;

sub new {
  my $class = shift;
  my $dbh = DBI->new(@_);
  bless \$dbh, $class;
}

sub select_from_systems {
    my $self = shift;
    $$self->selectcol_arrayref(...);
}
```

Then:

```
my $db = MyConnection->new(@credentials);
...;
my $result = $db->select_from_systems;
```

To model the object, I used a simple scalar reference here, but you may want traditional hash-based OO (or just use Moose).

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like a case where you should consider using object-oriented Perl. If you're not familiar with object oriented programming, one of the benefits is that you can have a group of functions which all operate on some common data (in this case, your database reference).

A nice low-level introduction to OO Perl is [perlootut on Perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlootut.html), although it appears popular to use modules like Moose when you're doing large-scale object-oriented programming in Perl.

Now, behind the scenes, Perl still passes around the object (a reference of some sort, usually a hash ref), and with basic OO Perl, the functions themselves still need to explicitly handle that. However, it makes the calling semantics nicer, such as the following:

```
my $database_object = new DatabaseObject("dbi:SQLite:dbname=db.db");
$database_object->select_from_systems();
```

The corresponding function definitions would be something like:

```
package DatabaseObject;
sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    my $dbpath = shift;
    my $dbh = DBI->connect( $dbpath, "", "") or die;

    my $self = {_dbh => $dbh};
    bless $self, $class;
    return $self;
}

sub select_from_systems {
    my $self = shift;
    return $self->{_dbh}->selectcol_arrayref("SELECT hostname FROM systems");
}
```